# WordPress taxonomy checkboxes

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, meta-boxes

I have a metabox in my post editor which allows me to pick a single category, I would like this changed to a checkbox where more than one can be picked. I have worked on the following, I would imagine it's a case of changing **taxonomy_radio** to something like **taxonomy_checkbox**, however that crashes the metabox completely:

```
$meta_boxes['test_metabox'] = array(
    'id'         => 'test_metabox',
    'title'      => __( 'TEST', 'cmb' ),
    'pages'      => array( 'post', ),
    'context'    => 'normal',
    'priority'   => 'high',
    'show_names' => true,
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'name'     => __( 'Category', 'cmb' ),
            'desc'     => __( 'field description (optional)', 'cmb' ),
            'id'       => 'test-cat',
            'type'     => 'taxonomy_radio',
            'taxonomy' => 'category'
        ),
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that it needs to be changed to **taxonomy_multicheck**